# Setting the appearance of android activity programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.android

I ma going to set my application's user interface from code behind but it has been confronted with a bizarre issue which has totally stopped me. I have a linear layout inside the activity which is supposed to hold some elements (Other linear layouts) so I can have a kind of menu. The first linear layout is considered as a container and its children are the buttons. The problem is, ***only the first button is shown in the container and the others are ignored!***

For achieving this goal, first I coded some tags in the XAML file. I actually coded the basic structure of the menu.

```
<!--Menu Container!-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TopMenueHolder"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
      <!-- Buttons-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/MenueButton1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/MenueButton2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />etc
```

Then I tried to set their properties from code behind.

```
 private void SetTopMenueStyle()
        {
            var buttonWidth = Convert.ToInt16(ScreenWidth / 5);
            var menueButtonsList = new List<int>
            {
                Resource.Id.MenueButton1,
                Resource.Id.MenueButton2,
                Resource.Id.MenueButton3,
                Resource.Id.MenueButton4,
                Resource.Id.MenueButton5
            };

            foreach (var buttonId in menueButtonsList)
            {
                var button = FindViewById(buttonId) as LinearLayout;
                if (button != null)
                {
                    var layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    button.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                    button.Click += menueButton_Click;
                }
            }
        }
```

This method is called inside the `Oncreate` method. According to my android studies it has been placed in the correct position. I also debugged the source and found that the code had adjusted the all internal element's properties (width and height) well. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only thing which I need to do is to change the both parent and children orientation to the horizontal because these buttons are going to occupy the screen through the x-axis.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonsHolder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />etc
```